# getJSON only giving result on 2nd call

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I have a form that takes a city as input, then I'm using jQuery to get an ID of that location using the SongKick API, then I use that ID to get future events at that location, also using the SongKick API and jQuery.

The problem I'm having is that when I enter in a city and hit submit, the first call to the SongKick API never returns a result, but if I hit submit again without changing the city text, it works just fine (and works everytime after that with the same city text).

Any help is much appreciated.

HTML code:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="doSearch(this.locationtext.value);"> 
    <input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" size="60" name="locationtext" value="Enter a City" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Make it rain" />
  </form>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function doSearch(locations) {

jQuery.getJSON("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/locations.json?query=" + locations + "&apikey=eRACBJEh2i3NOewK&jsoncallback=?", function(locdata){
    // THIS CODE NEVER RUNS THE FIRST TIME
    // get metro area ID from SongKick result
    var getID = locdata.resultsPage.results.location[0].metroArea.id;

    // pass ID to another SongKick API call to get events at location
    jQuery.getJSON("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/metro_areas/" + getID + "/calendar.json?apikey=eRACBJEh2i3NOewK&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
       // do whatever with result
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Check your browser's error console and watch the Network tab (Firebug / Chrome Dev Tools) when you submit the form the first time.

Comment: Not sure that it will solve the problem, but I'd add update your event handler as follows: `onsubmit="doSearch(this.locationtext.value); return false;"`

Comment: The return false is exactly what I needed... so simple.

Comment: nnnnnn, could you add your comment as a solution to the problem so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the input value after preventing the form's submit event:

```
<form action="#" id="doSearch"> 
<input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" size="60" name="locationtext" value="Enter a City" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Make it rain" />
```

```
jQuery(function($){


   $("#doSearch").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();//prevent the form to be submitted

     var location = $(e.target).find('[name="location"]').val();

     //do what you need with location

   });

})
```

Comment: I think the `e.preventDefault()` is what's really needed. Also, jQuery will bind the selected element (`#doSearch`) to the `this` variable within the handler so you don't need `e.target`

Comment: What do you mean "after form submit"? The original question code runs on submit.

Comment: yes, `e.target` may not be needed, but I think it is a good practice, sometimes while working with object methods the `this` refers to the object itself and not the the DOM element, so to avoid future issues, I always use `e.target`, just a matter of preference.

Comment: forget about the "after form submit" it was a mistake I ll edit the post

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be due to how you're handling the form submission. Rather than using the `onsubmit` attribute, you should attempt to use unobtrusive methods to attach event handlers. jQuery makes this very easy.

```
<form action="#"> 
    <input type="text" size="60" name="locationtext" placeholder="Enter a City" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Make it rain" />
</form>

$("form").submit(function() {
    var loc = $("input[name='locationtext']", this).val();
    $.getJSON("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/locations.json?jsoncallback=?", {
        query: loc,
        apikey: "eRACBJEh2i3NOewK"
    }, function(data) {
        var getID = data.resultsPage.results.location[0].metroArea.id;
        alert(getID);
    });
    return false;
});​
```

Notice how the event handler returns `false` as well. This prevents the default action (submitting the form) from running

JSFiddle demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/VSt3R/2/